# asp.net application default file Index.aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, settings

how can i make it that when i go to (for example) `http://localhost:60288/` it does not show me a directory listing but rather opens the `Index.aspx` page? This works with `http://localhost:60288/Index.aspx` but i don't wish to have `Index.aspx` shown every time.

i also need links like `http://localhost:60288/?a=1` to work like `http://localhost:60288/Index.aspx?a=1` without the `Index.aspx` shown.

this used to work when i created a website project in visual studio, but now i'm using application project. how can I set this up?

i want / need this to work for all sub folders as well e.g. `http://localhost:60288/SubFolder/` should work as if it was linked to `http://localhost:60288/SubFolder/Index.aspx`

thnx

**edit** still did not manage it

Comment: There are specific issues in this respect with the development server - I can't find the references quickly or I'd add an answer. You need to test the behaviour in IIS.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Cassini (the built-in webserver used by Visual Studio) doesn't allow you to configure the Default Document that's used if you don't specify a filename in your URL. The 'Set as Start Page' option isn't the same thing, as you've found, since that only affects which page is first opened when you run the project, and doesn't affect subsequent page-loads.

However, Cassini does *have* a list of Default Documents - it just isn't configurable, and the list only contains "default.aspx" and "default.htm". The only way you could achieve what you want in Cassini is to rename all your "index.aspx" files to "default.aspx".

Comment: thank you very much :) default.aspx is just as good for us as index.aspx so we switched. i actually suggested to use the default.aspx before ;) EXCELLENT!

Comment: When I have a second_page.aspx open on the screen and i hit ISS it starts with that second page on the web page. It didn't really work for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way for me to do this was to use a mapping.  Inside your Web.config, insert the following:

```
<configuration>                                                                  
    <system.web>                                                                 
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />                       
        <urlMappings enabled="true">                                             
            <add url="~/" mappedUrl="~/index.aspx" />                
            <add url="~/default.aspx" mappedUrl="~/index.aspx" />                
        </urlMappings>                                                           
    </system.web>                                                                
</configuration>
```

Comment: Great answer man, so this solution works for both if I am using vs development server as well as Windows IIS am I right ? Also because other suggestions were using the defaultDocument under system.webserver but it did not work for development server for me.

Answer (score 2):

Go into the IIS manager (in control panel - administrative tools)

Right click - properties on the default website

Documents tab - ensure that 'enable default document' is ticked, and that index.aspx is in the list of default documents, up the top preferably.

Home directory tab - make sure you've got an application created (application name shouldn't be blank). Click the 'create' button if you need to.

asp.net tab - check that you've selected the correct version of the framework that you want.

Let me know how you go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IIS Manager to set the Default document(s) for your site/application.

Cassini (the development web server integrated in Visual Studio) doesn't support the possibility to change the default document.

And yes, you do need to be an administrator to configure IIS.

Comment: yeah. not sure how to do that and i did google it (perhaps my queries were wrong). another thing is i'm not using IIS (in the project properties) but rather the visual studio development server.

Comment: if i try switching to IIS server in the project properties i get the error message that i need to run visual studio as administrator PLUS install some additional components (listed): internet information services, iis6 metabase and iis6 configuration compatibility, asp.net.!?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove or rename your index.aspx , so that it will show the directory listing when runs unless you set another page as start page.

For the second thing, u can use ASP.NET URL masking feature

Comment: it already does show directory listing when accessing `http://localhost:60288/` and this is exactly what i do NOT want. i want to access `http://localhost:60288/` and have the `Index.aspx` page be started / shown.