# Change built-in webserver to use 'Index.aspx' as default page

Tags: visual-studio-2010, localhost, default

When I run my application on localhost I get a directory listing and have to click on 'Index.aspx' to view the page.

I have already set the `Set As Start Page` to 'Index.aspx', which means when I press 'F5', 'Index.aspx' is opened.

This works fine, but when navigating through the site, if there is a link, such as '/FolderName', I get a directory listing, and have to manually change the URL to '/FolderName/Index.aspx'.

I believe this is because by default, the default page is 'Default.aspx'?

Is it possible to change this to 'Index.aspx'? It would save me a lot of time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK this is not configurable. Your best option would be to rename all your index.aspx files to default.aspx. See the following link with an accepted answer to back up mine. Have fun with your renames :)

[asp.net application default file Index.aspx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737153/asp-net-application-default-file-index-aspx)

Comment: urgh :/ I don't think google or SEO team are going to be happy to hear that! Cheers @musefan

Comment: @Curt, No probs - I think SEO people like slippers, buy them a pair to keep them happy :D