# ASP.NET Default Document

Tags: asp.net, html, hosting, web-hosting

i have default.aspx and index.html. I uploaded both to the server, but i want my first page start with index.html. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure it in the properties of the virtual directory hosting the ASP.NET application. Put `index.html` before `default.aspx`

[image]
<sub>(source: [plus2net.com](http://www.plus2net.com/designs/images/default-iis.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 8):

If you do not have access to IIS, and you are hosted on IIS 7 (Windows Server 2008), you may want to put this into your `web.config` file:

```
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <clear / >
            <add value="index.html" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```

Source: [How to add a default document with IIS7 web.config](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/03/22/how-to-add-a-default-document-with-iis7-web-config.aspx)

Comment: This is the correct solution, but watch out if you copy and paste it.  There's a space between the `/` and the `>` in the `<clear/>` tag.  Since it's less than a six-character fix, I can't edit it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the order of default document list to bring index.htm to the top, on IIS6 this found on the Documents tab of Properties dialog on the site in IIS manager.

Answer (score 2):

in your default.aspx page write this in your code behind if you don't have access to IIS.

```
Response.Redirect("index.htm");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set this up in IIS. In the IIS manager, this will be under the `Documents` tab.