# ASP.NET Web Application. How do I change the default page when app is enetered

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set Default Page in Asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913058/set-default-page-in-asp-net)
>   [ASP.NET Default Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012044/asp-net-default-document)

I have removed the default.aspx from my web application. Now when I run the application it only displays the contents of the directory in the browser. May I ask where the line of code/setting is to change the entry point to the site, for example the first page served is forum.aspx and not default.aspx

Regards

E

Comment: this is an IIS setting. http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/defaultDocument

Comment: so a web application must always use a Default.aspx? IIS dictates this?

Comment: no, you can setup this also on web.config -> http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/defaultDocument

Comment: Thank you very much for answering the question, all sorted now!

Comment: http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/03/22/how-to-add-a-default-document-with-iis7-web-config.aspx

Comment: Not really enough detail in this question. Do you mean on IIS? If so which version of IIS?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012044/asp-net-default-document

Answer (score 5):

The default document, is an IIS setting. You can change it also from web.config using this as sample:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <defaultDocument enabled="true">
         <files>
            <add value="home.html" />
         </files>
      </defaultDocument>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Find all details at : http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/defaultDocument