# Setting start page in web hosting ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, plesk

Parallel Plesk is not opening default page on my domain name which I've set in the default directories, instead it is opening a login page of my ASP.NET web application. However it opens default page on my domain name once I logged in by giving right credentials.
Here is my web.config file:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH"></forms>
    </authentication>      
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="20896" />
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
</system.web>

<location path="UserPanel.aspx">
    <system.web>
         <authorization>
             <allow users="*"/>
         </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: Where you setting the default page?

Comment: Plesk >> Websites & Domains >> Show Advanced Options >> Virtual Directories >> Directory Properties

Comment: Is it iis your hosting in?

Comment: @Izzy yes, it opens Login.aspx while I want to make UserPanel.aspx my start page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are hosting on IIS (7 or later), inside the `<system.webServer>` (of your `web.config`) add:

```
<defaultDocument>
    <files>
        <clear/>
        <add value="UserPanel.aspx" />
    </files>
</defaultDocument>
```

Comment: Try changing the value to `UserPanel.aspx` (edited)?

Comment: I think you are looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421778/asp-net-site-default-document-in-subfolder#answer-421836