# How to change aplication startup path on page in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I have an asp net project with name: DocCat , same name of application in IIS. 
When i open my asp net application from visual studio(iis express) it has path like this:
http://localhost:49727/Pages/Main.aspx

But when i want to open it in IIS i have this path :
http://localhost:49727/DocCat/
and it open only folders , not my startup page.
I need to rename start page path of my web application in IIS, to http://localhost:49727/Pages/Main.aspx
what can i do for this?

I tried :

1) Add this code to Webcongif file :

```
  <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
              <add  value="Pages/Main.aspx" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
```

2)Set default document to Main.aspx or Pages/Main.aspx
3) Add virtual catalogue with virtual path Pages/Main.aspx and physical path : BigCar/BigCar/Pages
**How can i rename startup path in IIS?**

Edit. Suggested question didn't solve my problem - because startuo page in IIS open FOLDER , not the page - likle this :
[image: http://imgur.com/a/O5XGJ]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [asp.net site default document in subfolder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421778/asp-net-site-default-document-in-subfolder)

Comment: @ChristopherTrevor no duplicates, read my edit plz

Comment: Your files dont seem to have actually been published, but rather that they are the raw source files. In Visual Studio did you right click and publish? You will then need to copy the resulting files from there to your site directory. Then follow the advice given on the previous link.

Comment: are you adding right directory in IIS? i think you need to add one more level of directory means DOCCAT which is shown in folder. please try to remap path to this directory and see whether it is working?

Comment: @ChristopherTrevor Yep, my project wasn't published , i add default document and now path is right, but i have error that my page wasn't found , but physical path is right and i can open this file in studio

Comment: If you have a look at the link from earlier, you need to have a document in the root that can serve as a default document. So either you need to move main.aspx out of the pages folder or you need to add a default.aspx page in the root and in the page load of that page redirect to main.aspx. I would normally leave my login page in the root and use that as the default document.

Comment: I have undeleted my original answer below. I will edit it to include the answers from the comments. If this answer helps you please mark as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are newbie in IIS like me i think this might help you:

- First of All deploy your project(not just copy your folder with project into iis folder)
- Turn on windows features like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/12867753/4559369
- Enable default documents like this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754807(v=ws.10).aspx

Now all work for me!

Answer (score 1):

If you browse to your site in IIS, you will find a config option called default document. Make sure you add Main.aspx to that list, preferably to the top.

Edit:
If you have all your pages in a subfolder you would need to either move the default document into the root or create a default.aspx in the root and redirect from that page load as IIS cannot use pages in subfolders as the default document.

Comment: nope, i make like this, but iis didn't see it, but thanks for help . I have an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/12867753/4559369

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable default documents in the IIS manager?

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754807(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: thanks , but i have another problem, iis didn't see my aspx file.