# Hosted Files in IIS Directly Open when i enter IP Address in Tool bar

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am developing a project using Asp.net  and Hosted in my system Internet Information System its works fine. when i enter my IPor port number and then slash give file name with extension

Every time I Enter:000:000.0.0:11/Main/Login.aspx then only its open.

I need when I enter IP in toolbar its open my main page Directly.

I don't know how to handle this whether change in IIS or C# web config code anyone can help. How to rectify and solve the problem?

Comment: depends upon port number

Comment: huh? Did you try what I posted? What do you mean 'depends on port number'? Do you have a default page set up at the moment? What happens when you set Login.aspx as the default?

Comment: i set login.aspx default its not opening

Comment: So what do you see? Blank screen? Same error? When responding please be a bit more detailed.

Comment: it's open like <dir>filename

Comment: You have directory browsing enabled. Disable it https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731109(v=ws.10).aspx see what a difference it makes when you explain?!

Comment: HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Comment: OK so that means it looked for a default file in the root folder, couldn't find one, so it tried to browse and it couldn't. For starters put an index.html in the root (this is usually C:\inetpub\wwwroot but it depends what you have configured) and see if that one appears. If so we can move to the next stage which is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421778/asp-net-site-default-document-in-subfolder